# Why does my material not show up in this particular car model?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials

I have been working on a lot of car 3d models by downloading them, applying materials and rendering. I've done it for a lot of cars.

The problem is that I downloaded an AMG C63 car from animium.com

The model was great. But when I applied materials it turned out black.

[image]

i even checked the normals it was correct. But still it did not show up

Why?

Comment: it looks like some image textures are missing, so you need to open the Mettalic Paint node group, find the Image Texture nodes, and reopen the images that are supposed to be assigned to each Image Texture node so that Blender knows the path in your hardrive files.

Comment: No. I was putting that material to the front bumper. That nodegrp does not contain textures. If it has no textures, then it must have shown up pink.